# How do I copy with scp with a wildcard(*) in the destination path?

Tags: bash, shell, copy, wildcard

Is it possible to get the value of what a wildcard matched to? I.e. I want to do

```
scp -r user@host:some/path/with/*/file.txt cp/to/*/file.txt
```

With the command above, I want

```
some/path/with/TEST/file.txt --> cp/to/TEST/file.txt
some/path/with/OTHER/file.txt --> cp/to/OTHER/file.txt
```

**EDIT:**
I'll add some more data of my actual setup, which might make it clearer.

On my server I have the structure

```
server $ pwd
~/sixtrack/simulations
server $ ls
run0001
run0002
run0003
...
```

Each `run*` is a directory, containing files like `run*/summary.dat`, `run*/tracks.dat` etc. I could copy everything over to my own computer like

```
pingul $ scp -r 'user@host:sixtrack/simulations/*' .
```

However, I would like to not copy over *every* file, instead just some. Because all files are named the same and only separated through the directory, I have to respect the structure. As such, I would like `host:sixtrack/simulations/run0001/summary.dat` to go into my local folder `/Users/pingul/Workspace/simulations/run0001/summary.dat`.

Running

```
pingul $ pwd
/Users/pingul/Workspace/simulations
pingul $ scp -r 'user@host:sixtrack/simulations/*/summary.dat' */.
```

Does not accomplish what I want. Adding the `-v` option as suggested prints out

```
Executing: cp -r -- run0001/. run0100/.
Executing: cp -r -- run0002/. run0100/.
Executing: cp -r -- run0003/. run0100/.
...
```

and I only get one `summary.dat` in `run0100`. All other directories are empty (i.e. `run0001`, `run0002`, ...)

Is what I want possible?

Comment: Do you have a folder called cp...?

Comment: @123 No, it is just meant to be readable. As in, "copy to ...".

Comment: `cp` in `verbose` mode i.e. `-v` flag could print the destination directory full path.

Comment: @Inian Could you please elaborate how I would use it to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @pingul: Add a flag `-v` in your scp, to see what I have mentioned before. I have a concern, do you just want to know the destination paths expanded by wildcard or perform any operation?

Comment: @Inian Thanks for your input. I added additional information in the question, and also the output from `-v` as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to expand `*` *before* running a
command or *after* running it and whether you want to do it
interactively or not.

If you want to expand it *before* running a command interactively you can either use `insert-completions (M-*)` or `glob-expand-word (C-x *)` described in `man bash`:

```
   glob-expand-word (C-x *)
          The word before point is treated as a pattern for
          pathname expansion, and the list of matching filenames
          is inserted, replacing the word.  If a numeric argument
          is sup- plied, an asterisk is appended before pathname
          expansion.

   insert-completions (M-*)
          Insert all completions of the text before point that
          would have been generated by possible-completions.
```

To use these functions put a cursor before or after `*` and press either <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>*</kbd>:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/expand-glob
$ ls
FILE
$ cp /tmp/expand-*/*
```

Now put your cursor after the last `*`, don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
but <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> and you'll get this

```
$ cp /tmp/expand-glob/FILE
```

If you want to expand `*` to test command in the script then neither
`scp` nor `cp` is a good option because the cannot run in `dry-run`
mode. You should go with something like `rsync` that would show what
files it *would* transfer if it was actually run like this:

```
$ rsync  -vn --relative /tmp/expand-*/* .
/tmp/
/tmp/expand-scp/
/tmp/expand-scp/a
/tmp/expand-scp/b
/tmp/expand-scp/c
/tmp/expand-scp/mmmm32
```

***EDIT*:**

How about this:

```
$ rsync -avn -R --rsync-path="cd sixtrack/simulations && rsync"  user@host:run*/summary.dat .
```

`-n` stands for *dry-run*.  With this option `rsync` will only print how will recreate a remote directory structure in current directory. In your case it will be something like:

```
receiving incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:45:36 run0001
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0001/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run00010
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run00010/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0002
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0002/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0003
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0003/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0004
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0004/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0005
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0005/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0006
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0006/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0007
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0007/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0008
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0008/summary.dat
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0009
-rw-r--r--              0 2016/10/13 12:23:18 run0009/summary.dat
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure how this is applicable to my situation, but I might have been unclear in my question. I added some more specific information in the post. Could you explain how I would use your case in my scenario?

Comment: It works like a charm! Mind amending your answer so it also includes the final call? (i.e. I need to add ` .` to your line above for it to actually do the copy)

Comment: @pingul: I'm glad it works for you! I added a missing dot.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is impossible since `cp`/`scp` commands take only a single destination. However you can easily simulate it with some very straightforward scripting:

```
for d in *
do
    scp -r user@host:some/path/with/"$d"/file.txt cp/to/"$d"/file.txt
done
```

It can also be written on a single line as

```
for d in *; do scp -r user@host:some/path/with/"$d"/file.txt cp/to/"$d"/file.txt; done
```

Comment: I tried this before, however every call generates a password prompt which makes the method unfeasible.